# django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: BuildingAddress has no field named 'False'

Tags: python, django, django-models, geodjango, django-import-export

```
class BuildingAddress(models.Model):
  id = models.CharField(max_length=12,primary_key = True)
  address = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  city = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  zip = models.CharField(max_length=10)
  state = models.CharField(max_length=2)
  primpgon = models.BigIntegerField()
  numpgons = models.BigIntegerField()
  x = models.FloatField()
  y = models.FloatField()
  censusbloc = models.CharField(max_length=15)
  objectid = models.BigIntegerField()
  geom = models.MultiPolygonField(srid=4326)
```

and then I am trying to import my shape file to this model. I wrote the below script.

```
import os
from django.contrib.gis.utils import LayerMapping
from .models import BuildingAddress

no_address_mapping = {
  'id' : 'ID',
  'address' : 'Address',
  'city' : 'City',
  'zip' : 'ZIP',
  'state' : 'State',
  'primpgon' : 'PrimPgon',
  'numpgons' : 'NumPgons',
  'x' : 'X',
  'y' : 'Y',
  'censusbloc' : 'CensusBloc',
  'objectid' : 'ObjectID',
}
no_address_shp = os.path.abspath(
  os.path.join(
     os.path.dirname(__file__),
    'building/WestDV_CA_BF_NoAddress_region.shp'))

def run(verbose=True):
  lm = LayerMapping(
    BuildingAddress, no_address_shp, no_address_mapping,
    transform=False, encoding='iso-8859-1')
 lm.save(strict=True, verbose=verbose)
```

And then I run this file in shell.

When I am try to run this file I am getting the `django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: BuildingAddress has no field named 'False'` Error. I don't understand why this error happend. I am not creating any field name as False. But it throws the Field name false doesn`t exist.

Comment: what's the line throwing the error?

Comment: line 31, in run
    transform=False, encoding='iso-8859-1',

Comment: Does it work without the transform=False?

Comment: No It's not working

Comment: Even I remove "transform=False" it throws the same error

Comment: Can you post the entire stacktrace?

Comment: It seems odd that you're passing the `BuildingAddress` class itself when creating a new `LayerMapping`. Shouldn't you be passing an instance of `BuildingAddress`? Can you post the `LayerMapping` code please?

Answer (score 0):

You did not add mapping to your `geom` field. Supposing you want to map there some multi-polygon geometry your mapping dictionary should look like:

```
no_address_mapping = {
  'id' : 'ID',
  'address' : 'Address',
  'city' : 'City',
  'zip' : 'ZIP',
  'state' : 'State',
  'primpgon' : 'PrimPgon',
  'numpgons' : 'NumPgons',
  'x' : 'X',
  'y' : 'Y',
  'censusbloc' : 'CensusBloc',
  'objectid' : 'ObjectID',
  'geom': 'MULTIPOLYGON'
}
```